.pth to .onnx conversion break the model u2net
The task is as follows: the site needs to add functionality for removing the background from the image of a car disk.
I decided to use the rembg library as a basis: https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg
This library in turn works on the basis of u2net: https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net
However, the standard u2net model removes all the background from the outside, leaving the space inside the disk untouched - between the spokes, holes, etc.
After googling a bit, I came to the conclusion that I can further train the u2net model for my specific needs.
The algorithm of actions is as follows:

further train the model
load it into rembg
use a custom model for cropping

I managed to train the standard u2net model, it cuts out black and white masks perfectly as I need.
However, when converting the model from .pth to .onnx format (which is required for working in rembg), it starts to work poorly.
The masks are blurry and soapy. I tried to convert the standard untrained u2net model
and use it in rembg - the result is the same, the masks are blurry, background cropping does not work.
Therefore, the conclusion is that the training was successful.
The problem is in the conversion.
So here are examples of the mask of my trained model.
Original image
The mask that my trained model generates
The mask that my trained model generates after converting to .onnx format
To generate a mask in u2net I use:
python3 u2net_test.py

To generate a mask in rembg I use the command:
rembg i -om -m u2net_custom -x '{"model_path": "~/.u2net/u2net_custom.onnx"}' 55.jpg 55.png

I tried to convert the finished model. Here is the conversion code:
import torch
import torch.onnx
from model.u2net import U2NET

def load_model(model_path, model_class):
    checkpoint = torch.load(model_path, map_location='cpu')
    if isinstance(checkpoint, dict) and 'state_dict' in checkpoint:
        model = model_class()
        model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    else:
        model = model_class()
    model.eval()
    return model

def convert_to_onnx(model, output_path):
    dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 320, 320)
    torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, output_path, opset_version=12,
                          dynamic_axes={'input': {0: 'batch_size', 2: 'height', 3: 'width'},
                                        'output': {0: 'batch_size', 2: 'height', 3: 'width'}})
    print(f"success {output_path}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="conversion PyTorch to ONNX")
    parser.add_argument('--model-path', type=str, required=True, help='path to .pth file')
    parser.add_argument('--output-path', type=str, required=True, help='save ONNX file')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    model = load_model(args.model_path, U2NET)
    convert_to_onnx(model, args.output_path)

and tried to save the model during the training process:
        if ite_num % save_frq == 0:
            timestamp = int(time.time())
            filePath = model_dir + model_name+"_%d_%d." % (ite_num, timestamp)

            torch.save(net.state_dict(), filePath + 'pth')

            dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 320, 320)
            net.eval()
            torch.onnx.export(net, dummy_input, filePath + 'onnx', opset_version=12)

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_tar_loss = 0.0
            net.train()  # resume train
            ite_num4val = 0

I tried changing settings, changing library versions, changing opset_version and everything else that chatGpt suggests.
The result is always the same.
After conversion the model stops working.
What mistakes did I make?

I found a solution.
I continued searching and came across this tutorial:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/bumbleboss/u2net-pth-to-onnx
I finalized the conversion according to the tutorial:
import torch
import torch.onnx
from model import U2NET

def convert(model_path, output_path):
torch_model = U2NET(3, 1)
torch_model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path, 
map_location=torch.device('cpu')), strict=False)  # Добавлен map_location
torch_model.eval()

x = torch.randn(1, 3, 320, 320, requires_grad=True)
torch_out = torch_model(x)

torch.onnx.export(
    torch_model,
    x,
    output_path,
    export_params=True,
    opset_version=11,
    do_constant_folding=True,
    input_names=['input'],
    output_names=['output'],
    dynamic_axes={'input': {0: 'batch_size'}, 'output': {0: 'batch_size'}}
)

print(f"success {output_path}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="conversion PyTorch to ONNX")
parser.add_argument('--model-path', type=str, required=True, help='path to .pth file')
parser.add_argument('--output-path', type=str, required=True, help='save ONNX file')

args = parser.parse_args()
convert(args.model_path, args.output_path)

Now rembg perfectly cuts out the background on car rims:
origin
removed_bg
I hope it helps someone!

can you update your answer to include include context from the tutorial, especially the key steps that your final code uses?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
